# TeXstudio can't write on file '.pdf'

Tags: pdf, texstudio

Having this problem for a while now while using TexStudio:
I write a paper in TeXstudio and use the "Build & View" button, no problems, code works and example view appears on the right side.
However, as soon as I save my `.tex`-file, I can no longer watch the example view, nor will it create a `.pdf`.
When I look into the folder, there isn't even a `.pdf`-file there. When clicking on the error it brings me to a `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` file, giving me a red line at:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{pgf@lib@fade@east}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
    color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}
```

Anyone got any ideas? This issue turned up out of nowhere and happens with literally every file I have.

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fbru2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/36268036_1963806090296596_5337599310370439168_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=97db5f2b72b7cc67ed338d3a7886ae44&oe=5BEAB3EA))</sub>

As you can see the only error i get is about writing on the pdf, which is not opened at the time and actually does not exist: here is a picture of the folder:
[image: folder]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fbru2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/36311519_1963807910296414_5124352530561630208_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=fbe4a57750a0fad3ead7643f06e788d4&oe=5BB6BC33))</sub>

Comment: I suppose you viewed the pdf with the Adobe Reader? It locks the pdf to prevent  overwriting

Comment: Not really, texstudio doesnt seem to be creating a pdf file at all (anymore), i usually just watch the pdf on the right halve of texstudio after "Build and View". when i look into the folder of the file, there is no pdf there. i also tried creating a new file, saving right away and then compile, still got an error even though there shouldnt have been a pdf file to begin with since all i did was save the .tex file

Comment: compile your document on the command line to check if it contains errors.

Comment: I suspect that some other file was set up as root file and so txs compile that file instead of the new one. In Option menu you can find the root options.

Comment: I am not sure what either of you mean or how to do it... sorry, im quite new to this

Comment: Which TeXstudio version are you using? And on what OS?

Comment: Windows 8.1, Texstudio 2.8.4

Comment: That's extremely old.. any reason why you're still on 2.8.4? Also try compiling on command line: Open command prompt, `cd` to the folder containing the problematic `document.tex` file and run `pdflatex document.tex`, do you get a pdf? Any error messages?

Comment: I installed it when i started college and never had any issues so i also never updated. How exactly do i "cd" to the folder? I don't really understand what you're asking me to do

Comment: While the folder is open, do the keyboard shortcut `Alt+D`, copy the folder path with `Ctrl+C`. Open command prompt, type `cd "<path>"` including the quotes, where `<path>` should be replaced with the one you copied earlier. Click enter. Then type `pdflatex document.tex` and press`Enter`.

Comment: In the meantime, can you also try updating your TeXstudio? "... never had any issues...", well now you do.

Comment: Ok weird thing just happened, i was getting syntax erros concerning not putting in the right name of the folder. I assumed it was because of a space in one of the folder-names, so i made a new folder, saved my file into that one, compiled, and now it compiles just fine...

Comment: Is it possible that was the cause of all this mess?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe some write access issues with that particular folder then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.