# TeXstudio can't write on pdf file

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texstudio

I recently started having compilation problems after updating my TeXstudio to the newest version (3.0.1) using Windows 10. Whenever I try to compile any tex files, I encounter the following error:

> I can't write on file `document.pdf'. \end{document}

As an example, I created a new file from a template using the article class:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{Test}
\author{Marcelo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

I have found similar questions on StackExchange, and tried some of the suggestions such as:

- Make sure that Adobe Reader is closed and delete the pdf file generated
- Compile from the command prompt using "pdflatex document.tex"
- Make sure I have writing permissions - this should not be a problem since I am writing to my desktop

But I am still getting the same error:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.10)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.17)  27 OCT 2020 11:22 entering
> extended mode
> **./document.tex (document.tex LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
> (C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
> Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
> (C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
> File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
> \c@part=\count175 \c@section=\count176 \c@subsection=\count177
> \c@subsubsection=\count178 \c@paragraph=\count179
> \c@subparagraph=\count180 \c@figure=\count181 \c@table=\count182
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip47 \belowcaptionskip=\skip48
> \bibindent=\dimen138 )
> (C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-p
> dftex.def File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support:
> PDF output (pdfTeX) \l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count183
> \l__pdf_internal_box=\box47 ) (document.aux) \openout1 =
> `document.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
> 7. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
> line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:
> Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:
> ... okay on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
> line 7. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7. LaTeX Font Info:
> External font `cmex10' loaded for size (Font)              <12> on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    External font` cmex10' loaded for
> size (Font)              <8> on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:
> External font `cmex10' loaded for size (Font)              <6> on
> input line 9.
>
> ! I can't write on file `document.pdf'. Please type another file name
> for output ! Emergency stop.  ...shipout:D \box_use:N
> \l_shipout_box
> l.17 \end{document}
>
> *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  410 strings out of
> 480236  7293 string characters out of 2879607  268785 words of memory
> out of 3000000  17041 multiletter control sequences out of
> 15000+200000  539335 words of font info for 43 fonts, out of 3000000
> for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 41i,6n,47p,132b,189s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no
> output PDF file produced!

It would be great if anyone had suggestions on how to solve this problem besides reinstalling TeXstudio, which I have already tried.

Thank you!!

Related questions:

- [Explain "Please type another output file name: "](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/explain-please-type-another-output-file-name)
- [MiKTeX can't write on pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78362/miktex-cant-write-on-pdf-file)
- [TeXstudio can't write on file '.pdf'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432565/texstudio-cant-write-on-file-pdf)

Comment: you probably have multiple instances of said PDF open in different kinds of PDF readers or by the operating system itself.

Comment: But this problem persists even when I create a new file from a template as in the example I provided - meaning that there is no PDF file to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem at [Can't write on file *.pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553773/cant-write-on-file-pdf?rq=1). Apparently, Avast can block pdflatex so that no PDF is generated.